# Ошибка в ajax запросе

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ошибка в ajax запросе всегда выводит содержимое (data == '1') то есть пишет, что данные не переданы сам ajax запрос срабатывает страница не перезагружается помогите 2 день мучаюсь

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickButtonForm").bind("click", function () {
        $.ajax ({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#password").val(), email: $("#email").val()},
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function (){
                $("#information").text ("Expectaton data...")
            },
            success: function (data){
                // в случае, когда пришло success. Отработало без ошибок
                if (data == '0')
                    $("#error").text("Occured error speak administraor").removeClass("error").addClass("success").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(3000);
                //   $("#error").text("You success registration").removeClass("error").addClass("success").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                // в случа ошибок

                else (data == '1')
                $("#error").text("Occured error speak administraor").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(3000);

            }

        });
    });
});
```

вот html шаблон

```
<form role="form" class="formForMe" id="register_form" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="input form-control" id="login" placeholder="Введите Ваш будующий логин для входа" required autofocus />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="input form-control" placeholder="Введите Ваш пароль для входа" required />
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="add-on">@</span></span>
        <input type="text" class="input form-control" id="email" placeholder="Ваш существующий email" required autofocus />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
            <button type="button" class="clickButtonForm btn btn-labeled btn-success" id="clickButtonForm">
                <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Войти</button>
            <button onclick="location.href='../index.html'" type="submit" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>Назад</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Забыли свой пароль?</a></p>
</form>
```

и php обработчик ajax.php

```
<?php
if(isset(($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {      
    echo 0;
} else {
    echo 1;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Ошибка вот тут: `else (data == '1')`. Кажется, вы забыли дописать пару букв и пробел.

Comment: не понял каких букв

Comment: И в php скобка лишняя. Неужели редактор кода не показывает? Должно быть `if(isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {`

Comment: @Koly после `else` всегда идет блок `{ ... }`. `else` - "тогда" - не предполагает никаких условий, как у вас. А у вас нужно добавить `if` чтобы получилось `else if(...){ ... }`. `тогда если (условие){действия}`

Comment: if (data == '0')  
    {
       $("#error").text("Occured error speak administraor").removeClass("error").addClass("success").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(3000);
                 //   $("#error").text("You success registration").removeClass("error").addClass("success").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                // в случа ошибок
    }
     else (data == '1') {
                    $("#error").text("Occured error speak administraor").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(3000);}

Comment: так пишет ошибку

Comment: почему не исправили ошибку, на которую мы вам указали? добавьте `if` после `else`.

Comment: elseif (data == '1')  так тоже ошибка , извините если туплю, но все же я хочу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Сравните свой вариант `elseif (data == '1')` с моим `else if(...){ ... }`. Пробел же, ну.

Comment: else if (data == '1') {
                    $("#error").text("Occured error speak administraor").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(3000);
                
    }

Comment: сделал так ничего не происходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44250/discussion-between---and-koly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно исправить условие в ajax.php. По логике, сервер должен возвращать "0" если поля заполнены и "1" если нет. Но на данный момент, от сервера всегда будет возвращаться "0", потому что условие проверяет не заполненность переменных, а просто их наличие. Т.е. пустые login, password и email будут тоже приниматься.

Поэтому, условие нужно исправить на такое:

```
if(!empty($_POST['login']) and !empty($_POST['password']) and !empty($_POST['email'])) {
```

Теперь будет проверяться не только наличие полей, но также и их заполненность.

Кроме этого , в представленном коде нужно исправить следующие ошибки:

в ajax.php убрать лишнюю скобку. Должно быть так:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])) {
```

в js нужно исправить некорректный `else`. Правильно так:

```
else if (data == '1')
```

Про условные операторы в javascript можно подробно и с примерами прочитать здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse